# Modify Backbone AJAX responses before they hit the model

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I am currently getting JSON responses from my server as follows:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "number" : "123456",
    "name" : "Some Name",
    "client" {
        "com.test.domain.Client" : 5
    }
}
```

I need the responses to read like this:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "number" : "123456",
    "name" : "Some Name",
    "client" {
        "id" : 5
    }
}
```

I want to hook into all AJAX responses made by Backbone and replace any key matching `^com.test.domain.*$` with `id`.  Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the `parse` function in your model to change the received JSON to what you want. See http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse and http://backbonefu.com/2011/11/working-with-api-responses-in-backbone-js-using-parse/

Comment: Modifying the global parse response is what I needed Backbone.Model.prototype.parse, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by overriding the parse method in your model which receives this response.

Eg:

```
var SampleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

....

parse: function(serverResponse){
  var serverResponseString = JSON.stringify(serverResponse);
  var modifiedResponseString = serverResponseString.replace("com.test.domain.Client","id");

  return  JSON.parse(modifiedResponseString);

},

....

});
```

When you do fetch or save from the instances of the model, they will go through this parse method. So you can modify it to return the value you want.

Comment: +1, I will use this technique, but using a regular expression and in Backbone.Model.prototype.parse